# What type of dandelion is this?

Tags: identification, wildflowers, dandelions

Years ago, hiking in the Malibu CA region, I saw this very unusual inflorescence that looked like a dandelion but isn't like any that I've ever seen before or since.  The yellow flowers in the corner of the picture might give a hint as to what plant this is from--but it's also possible that those are from a different plant.  If anyone can help identify this plant, I'd really appreciate it!

[image]

---

OOOOOH!  Could it be [*Achyrachaena mollis* ("blow wives")](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Achyrachaena_mollis_seedhead.jpg)?

Or maybe it is [*Uropappus lindleyi*, aka "silver puffs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uropappus).  I think this is a better match (an image search for *A. mollis* shows very different seed head morphology).

Comment: Any foliage with this? Seeing the leaves would be useful

Comment: @Bamboo Sadly, no:  this is the only photograph I have, and I was lucky to find it because I thought it had been lost until recently.

Comment: It could be related to globe gilia or _Gilia capitata_ or _Gilia congesta_ ...

Comment: @BenWelborn Thanks to your comment, I think I managed to find a good visual match!

Comment: We have something around here that's similar in the seed head department, Western Salsify

Comment: This is a tough one, and lots of fun! heropup, are you still thinking Uropappus? That's what it looks like to me!

Comment: @heropup I think that you should answer your own question... Uropappus!

Answer (score 4):

Let me just preface this by saying that I remember when I took that photo (which, based on the time stamp, was back in April 2013), I had searched on the internet with no success:  various searches by image failed, and searches using keywords like "dandelion" or "star dandelion" were hopelessly futile.

And just by sheer luck, Ben Welborn's comment suggesting *Gilia sp.* prompted an image search under that genus, which so happened to return a few results for *Uropappus*, which I think was misidentified as *A. mollis*, and eventually led to what I believe is the definitive genus, *Uropappus*, probably *Uropappus lindleyi*.  The resemblance in the seed head, at least, is unmistakable:

[image]

(Source:  [http://nativeplants.csuci.edu/uropappus-lindleyi.htm](http://nativeplants.csuci.edu/images/uropappus-lindleyi-3apr2013-35.jpg))

Again, I wish to thank Ben, and everyone who provided feedback, for helping in identifying this distinctive plant!